# Div Editable and More... More

Tags: javascript, html, replace, cpu-word, caret

Well,

I need to replace a word, in a div contentEdible property on, by the same word but formatted...
Like this:
`<div> My balls are big </div>`
To this (replace the word: balls):
`<div> My <font style="color:blue;">balls</font> are big </div>`

In a contentEditable this happens dinamically, while the user type the text the replacements happens. I think that a simple event onkeydown, onkeyup, or onkey press, can solve this part.
But, the trouble is with the caret, that after all that i tryed, it stay before the word replaced, when should be stay after. I tryed write some js code, tryed find some jquery scripts, but all them failed in this situation...

Any one has some ideia, or trick ?

I think:
--> Record the length of the word unformatted.
--> Delete this word
--> Put new word formatted.
--> Walk with the caret, to position based this formatted  word length.
--> Is it?
PS: I have to considerate a word in any place of this div.

I don't know how to write this code that do what i say above.

Correct me, if i'm wrong.

Since yet, thanks!

Edit[1]: I want that this works on **Mozilla Firefox**, specificlly;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only have IE6/7 on this machine, but maybe you can apply the concept to other browser versions of Ranges (or maybe this is cross-browser?).

Basically we store the cursor position, make our search/replacement, then put the cursor back where it was:

html:

```
<div id="content" contentEditable="true" onkeyup="highlight(this)">This is some area to type.</div>
```

and the script:

```
function highlight(elem) {
// store cursor position
var cursorPos=document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
var clickx = cursorPos.getBoundingClientRect().left; 
var clicky = cursorPos.getBoundingClientRect().top; 
// copy contents of div
var content = elem.innerHTML;
var replaceStart = '<font style="color:blue">';
var replaceEnd = '</font>';
// only replace/move cursor if any matches
// note the spacebands - this prevents duplicates
if(content.match(/ test /)) {
    elem.innerHTML = content.replace(/ test /g,' '+replaceStart+'test'+replaceEnd+' ');
    // reset cursor and focus
    cursorPos = document.body.createTextRange();
    cursorPos.moveToPoint(clickx, clicky);
    cursorPos.select(); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hum, i returned to the same previous problem... with cursor. now its crazy, it is going to begin... :S

I believe that some answer on Range object, or Selection object, something like this!

Comment: Did more research and posted a new solution. I've only tested it in IE7 but maybe its cross-browser, or you can find the equivalent methods.

Comment: Really, It works but just in IE... And i want a solution that works specially on FF; but tnks...