# Rewrite a IE Code to a FF Code

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, range, caret

This is the code (now is full):

HTML:

`<div id="content" contentEditable="true" onkeyup="highlight(this)">This is some area to type.</div>`

Javascript:

```
function highlight(elem){
    // store cursor position
    var cursorPos=document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
    var clickx = cursorPos.getBoundingClientRect().left; 
    var clicky = cursorPos.getBoundingClientRect().top; 
    // copy contents of div
    var content = elem.innerHTML;
    var replaceStart = '';
    var replaceEnd = '';
    // only replace/move cursor if any matches
    // note the spacebands - this prevents duplicates
    if(content.match(/ test /)) {
        elem.innerHTML = content.replace(/ test /g,' '+replaceStart+'test'+replaceEnd+' ');
        // reset cursor and focus
        cursorPos = document.body.createTextRange();
        cursorPos.moveToPoint(clickx, clicky);
        cursorPos.select(); 
    }   
}
```

Just woks on IE, unhapply. 
Anyone can 'adjust' this code, to work on FF too!...

Thanks

Edit[1]:
[Div Editable and More... More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366321/javascript-div-editable-and-more-more)

This code replaces a especific word by the same word formatted...
And the caret (cursor) stay always after the word replaced! <<< "This is the big"
But just works on IE, and I like so much to rewrite this code to work on FF... but I can't do it... Its so hard...

Anyone can help?

Edit[2]:
My problem is just with this part:

```
        // reset cursor and focus
        cursorPos = document.body.createTextRange();
        cursorPos.moveToPoint(clickx, clicky);
        cursorPos.select();
```

Because, moveToPotion and select functions just works on IE... Until then it is easy...
On FF there is another set of functions that make it possible... But i don't know how to write another code that do the same things. Do you got it?

Comment: Can we get a bit more of an explanation in what the intended result is first please?

Comment: This sounds like a `send-me-teh-codez` kind of question. Perhaps you could start the process, and ask us pointed questions when you run into any problems?

Comment: Is this in an editable document/element?

Comment: Tim Down: Yes! Is an editable div!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preserve the caret position by inserting a marker element at its current location before doing your replacement on the element's `innerHTML`. (Using DOM methods to traverse the text nodes and searching each for the text you want would be preferable to using `innerHTML`, by the way).

The following works, so long as the caret is not positioned within or adjacent to the word "text". I also added a timer to prevent calling this function every time a key is pressed and to wait for the user to stop typing for half a second.

```
function insertCaretMarker() {
    var range;
    var markerId = "sel_" + new Date() + "_" + ("" + Math.random()).substr(2);
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.collapse(true);
        var markerEl = document.createElement("span");
        markerEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\u00a0"));
        markerEl.id = markerId;
        range.insertNode(markerEl);
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        if (range.pasteHTML) {
            range.pasteHTML("<span id=\"" + markerId + "\">&nbsp;</span>");
        }
    }
    return markerId;
}

function restoreCaret(markerId) {
    var el = document.getElementById(markerId);
    var range;
    if (el) {
        if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            range = document.createRange();
            range.setStartBefore(el);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
            range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(el);
            range.collapse(true);
            range.select();
        }
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }
}

function preserveCaretPosition(func) {
    var id = insertCaretMarker();
    func();
    restoreCaret(id);
}

var highlightTimer;

function highlight(elem) {
    if (highlightTimer) {
        window.clearTimeout(highlightTimer);
    }
    highlightTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        highlightTimer = null;
        var replaceStart = '<b>';
        var replaceEnd = '</b>';
        // only replace/move cursor if any matches
        // note the spacebands - this prevents duplicates
        if (elem.innerHTML.match(/ test /)) {
            preserveCaretPosition(function() {
                elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(/ test /g, ' ' + replaceStart + 'test' + replaceEnd + ' ');
            });
        }
    }, 500);
}
```