# Periodically detecting specific strings inside of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, css, syntax, html, highlighting

I have a div element with contenteditable set to true, and I want to detect whether a certain string exists within the element, and if so, style it, giving the appearance of syntax highlighting (I've already looked at existing libraries/scripts, and none of them work the way I need them to).

What would be the best solution to this, while preserving compatibility with HTML5/CSS3 compliant browsers?

Comment: What scripts and ways have you looked into? The more information, the better the answer.

Comment: CodePress, CodeMirror, EditArea, MDK-Editor, Bespin, and Ymacs.

Comment: I really like Geshi (for PHP) - http://qbnz.com/highlighter/ - AJAX + PHP could solve this somehow. At any rate, you should pick a syntax highlighter unless you want to spend a very long time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I'd rather not use GeSHi. I don't want to put that much strain on my server (I won't be the only one using this).

If it was more efficient, I'd use it, but right now, it's rather slow.

Comment: Does my answer to this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398896/rewrite-a-ie-code-to-a-ff-code

Comment: Also, have you looked at how http://jsfiddle.net/ does this?

Comment: Actually, I haven't. I'll look into that though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is nearly always a good choice IMO, and here's a very lightweight plugin for it that I think does just what you're looking for.

http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html